# Unexpected "->" when delaying job dispatching using Carbon

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-queue

I'm trying to delay a Laravel Job dispatch. But when I try to run my function, I seem to encounter this

> syntax error, unexpected '->' (T_OBJECT_OPERATOR).

The error seems to be coming from the 3rd line of the code that I displayed.

That line of code is also copied from [this website](https://www.larashout.com/laravel-queues-step-by-step-guide).

Please advise me on what to do, and sorry if this seems like a rookie mistake.

```
class Auto_Order_C extends Controller {
    public function ordering() {
        $job = new Auto_Order_Job()->delay(Carbon::now()->addMinutes(5));
        $this->dispatch($job);
        return redirect()->back()->with("status", "Job submitted");
    }
}
```

Comment: Try separating out the logic. `$job = new AutoOrderJob(); $job->delay...`

Comment: alternatively, put it in parentheses: `(new Auto_Order_Job())->`

Comment: @aynber add your comment as an answer so it can be accepted;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to separate out the logic:

```
$job = new Auto_Order_Job();
$job->delay(Carbon::now()->addMinutes(5));
```

Or per Franz's comment, put the class creation in parenthesis:

```
$job = (new Auto_Order_Job())->delay(Carbon::now()->addMinutes(5));
```